# Spring @Service annotation with more values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to ask if there is possible in spring to annotate class with @Service with more than 1 value, something like this:

```
@Service({"ServiceName1","ServiceName2"})
public class ClassName {
}
```

The reason is i want to get same class when i am calling `applicationContext.getBean("ServiceName1");` or `applicationContext.getBean("ServiceName2");`

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Can you please describe your use case?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? A `@Service` annotated class is a singleton as default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just declare your bean in a configuration class instead, and specify multiple names in the Bean annotation:

```
@Bean(name = { "ServiceName1", "ServiceName2" })
public ClassName myService() {
    return new ClassName();
}
```

But if you're getting beans by name, from the application context, you've probably missed the whole point of dependency injection.

Comment: Up: If you need to ask how to do this and are using `getBean`, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think if we use @Component/ @Service annotations we can create only one bean instance for a class. If we need to create multiple beans for a single class we need to go with xml approach. Define the beans for the single Class in applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="ServiceName1" class="<ClassName Path>">  

</bean>
<bean id="ServiceName2" class="<ClassName Path>">  

</bean>
```